# How can I access Perl variables in Java?

Tags: java, perl

I need to get an array from Perl script to Java program.

Can we directly access that variable in Perl directly from Java, or is there any way to return that array from the Perl program to the Java program?

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to transfer data from one process to another (no matter what language) is to use serialized strings.

Serialize your array to eg. a JSON String and deserialize it in the target process. If its a really simple data format, you could also use a field delimiter and simply concatenate the array fields with the delimiter.

Comment: **Moved as a comment grom tweber's answer :** You wont get a more specific answer without furhter details about your problem. 
Are those other questions of you really unanswered? Please dont forget to accept answers if a problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

For accessing Java class from Perl, I would suggest [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Java). Once you have that  interface running you can easily pass different data structures.

Comment: This sounds like the opposite of what the question is seeking.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to do this would be to write the array in a csv format and have your have program read from this file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PeterHorvath This *is* an answer. Not a great one, but it is a valid response to the question. The root issue is that the question is very vague.

Comment: As per the question author, he wants to know a way to access an array present in a Perl script from his Java code. What I have suggested is to write the perl array into a csv file ( or maybe an xml file if the array is a complex structure ) and parse it in Java and transform it into a relevant data structure there. 

I am sorry for being vague, definitely I could have elaborated it further.